# Implement HTTP Request with Axios and DeepL API

Tags: axios

How can i implement properly this HTTP Request with Axios and DeepL API ?

```
POST /v2/translate?auth_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx> HTTP/1.0
Host: api.deepl.com
User-Agent: MyApp
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 54
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

auth_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&text=Hello, world&target_lang=DE
```

Comment: There are a few examples on axios usage. On it's github project [https://github.com/axios/axios#example](https://github.com/axios/axios#example). Please try that and update this question if you experience any issues.

Comment: Please provide details about the problem that you're facing, and what you've already tried. Also, update the tags accordingly

Comment: '405 Method Not Allowed' I don't understand why and 'cross-origin Request' error

Answer (score 2):

My request with Axios:

```
getTranslation ({ commit }, params) {
    axios
      .get(`https://api.deepl.com/v2/translate?auth_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&text=Hello,%20world&target_lang=DE`,
        {headers: {
          'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'

        }})
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response, 'response')
      })
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, it is a very bad idea to use an API key in front because the key is visible in the request, I passed everything in back and it works perfectly, like a charm